# String Validation in a Certain Format

Tags: c++, string, validation

I'm creating a simple chess game which uses shared memory. There are two players (Black,White) in the game and they are working in Strict Alternation principle. I get input from every player in turn-based sense and use them. My question is: I want the user to give the input like mov(a1,b2). After getting the input First: I want to validate if it is in the correct format and then I want to use the a1,b2 values in a function. Here is the part of my code:

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SHMSZ     27

int main() {
    int shmid;
    key_t key;
    char *shm;
    string cmd;
    int check =1;

    key = 111;

    /*
     * Locate the segment.
     */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, 0666)) < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        return 0;
    }

    /*
     * Now we attach the segment to our data space.
     */
    if ((shm = (char*) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        return 0;
    }

    cout << *shm << endl;
    while(check)
    {
        if(*shm == '*') //checks if other player finished the game
        {
            cout<<"End of the game. Thank you for playing." <<endl;
            *shm ='*';
            exit(1);
        }
        while(*shm == 'B')
        {

            cout << "Enter a move" << endl;
            cin >> cmd;

            if(cmd=="eog") // Finish the game
            {   
                cout<<"End of the game. Thank you for playing." <<endl;
                *shm ='*';
                exit(1);
            }
            *shm = 'W';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a regular expression would be what you need.

Comment: I'm below average in C++. do you know how to do it?

Comment: First, you'll need to specify more exactly what the correct format is, and how strictly you would like to validate it. For example, would you want to invalidate a square like a9 or z4? Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/regex/regex_match/ for information about regex usage in C++.

Comment: If you can't use C++11 standard you could also try here: [boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: The usual way to do this in a chess playing program is to have the program generate all possible moves, and then verify that the input is one of those.